# PhpStorm not deploying my files to a local server

Tags: deployment, phpstorm

I am coding a website and it uses PHP. I am using an Apache web server on my Linux machine.

My editor is PhpStorm and I am trying to configure the preview. The problem is that I set all the mappings and the deployment path but PhpStorm can't deploy my files and folders to the specified folders.

Any ideas of what is causing the problem?

Comment: Any errors? Checked permissions?

Comment: No errors, and i ran phpstorm with sudo

Comment: How exactly do you start the deployment process? What is the output?